# How to handle colSpan in the last row of the table?

Tags: html

How to make the last two entries in the given table in the link to appear in manner so that they both share 50% of the total width of the table for example colSpan should be 1.5 for each but that's not possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/3uLt69yt/

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>Savings</th>
 <th>Savings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
<td>$100</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>February</td>
<td>$100</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="1">Sum: $180</td>
 <td colspan="1">Sum: $180</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just add an extra empty td to the last row

Comment: I don't want any extra space in between them or at the sides, i want both to take exactly 50% of the width of the table

Comment: adding a new table inside the table is that  correct approach?

Comment: I wonder how to achieve the same results without introducing a new table inside the main table for example https://jsfiddle.net/koznjjnu/

Comment: What's the exact purpose of this last row ? The firts `td` of this row for example would be the total of what ?

Comment: I was working with the html tables and faced this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have three columns and want the last two cells to span 1.5 columns – which is impossible, `colspan` can only work with positive integers – you have to multiply 1.5 by a number that results in those two cells spanning a whole number of columns. In this case that multiplier is 2.

To do this, then, you simply have to update every cell elsewhere to have a `colspan` attribute doubling its current `colspan` value (those cells without a `colspan` attribute, which therefore span only one column, must be given `colspan="2"`), like so:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Month</th>
    <th colspan="2">Savings</th>
    <th colspan="2">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">January</td>
    <td colspan="2">$100</td>
    <td colspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">February</td>
    <td colspan="2">$100</td>
    <td colspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
    <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Updated [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3uLt69yt/2/).

This *feels* a little like a hacky workaround, but it is valid HTML, and avoids creating any new elements – although the `<table>` now explicitly has six columns rather than the original three; although given that no new elements are created they are implicit, rather than 'present' in the HTML.

From a user-interface perspective it's also worth noting that the last two cells – which span half of the table's width – don't have any clear relevance to the table headings, which may (or may not) be confusing to your site's users.

Comment: It works but it's a hack. What does it mean semantically ? How is it read by a screen reader ?

Comment: "*What does it mean semantically? How is it ready by a screen reader?*" - I honestly don't know. But given the dearth of information in the question I simply did the best I could to answer the question within the constraints. I don't think it's the worst option available, given the only other option is nesting other elements to contain the data. Which would be even less semantically correct I believe.

Comment: Really good answer and explanation; David i wish i had the option to double up vote it